Missing zoom/hand/camera/perspective gizmos
Said gizmos are missing in the 3D viewport. I can see the gimbal gizmo, and everything is on in the Viewport Gizmos submenu. Any way to bring them back? I’m using Blender 4.1 now, but I also have 3.1 where these gizmos are visible.


Maybe the Navigation Controls option is disabled in the Preferences > Inteface > Editors panel:

